# Dataframe column transpose in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have data in source file in the format

```
Open,0.001
High,0.001
Low,0.001
Close,0.001
Volume,0
Adj Close,0.001
SMA_20,0.0010000000000000005
SMA_50,0.0010000000000000007
date_of_trade,2016-02-05 00:00:00
code,AFT
Open,2.9300000000000002
High,2.9700000000000002
Low,2.8300000000000001
Close,2.8999999999999999
Volume,631100
Adj Close,2.8999999999999999
SMA_20,3.2214999999999998
SMA_50,3.0767999999999969
date_of_trade,2016-02-05 00:00:00
code,1PG
Open,6.9900000000000002
High,7.0999999999999996
Low,6.9000000000000004
Close,6.9000000000000004
Volume,4300
```

i want to convert into following format

```
open,high,low,close,volume,adj_close,sma_20,sma_50,data_of_trade,code
.001,.001,.001,0,.001,.0001000005,.0000100007,2016-02-05 00:00:00,aft
2.93,2.97,.......................................................,1pg
```

the first column in source file is column name and second is corresponding column value .

i tried pivot etc but couldn't make it to work.any help is welcome.

Comment: I having trouble understanding your desired output. Do you want a list all column names first, followed by all column values(ordered by column names)?

Comment: yes u r correct.i want to put column name in first row followed by data value in each row. pls see the format i mention in q

Comment: Row 1: Open, High, Low etc..                                                                          Row2: 0.01 etc.. ? Something like this? Where the order of row2 depends on the order of row1? Also, what is the question, do you want code to do this or what exactly?

Comment: yes correct yes i want to code it.i want to take source file input and convert into other format and save it as file . the order of row2 and other rows  should match order of rows 1. pls let me know if u have any other question.

Comment: In the input data, is second column guaranteed to be an integer? and is the first column guaranteed to be a string?

Comment: [df.pivot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot) is the right approach. please post your code and what exact problem have you encountered - error message, wrong shape of output?

Comment: no second column contain  string value on 10th 20th and so on  for column "code". also second column have lot of decimal values so no second column is not guaranteed to be integer in source file.

Comment: i dont have any code right now. I tried last night but couldn't make it to work so discarded the code. If anyone can explain me how to do with pivot I will see what mistake i was making.

Comment: FYI: if you don't @mention someone in your comments, we don't get any notifications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for [pivot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot) to properly work, you need add a unique identifier for each record, e.g. if 1 record is 10 rows long in the original data, then integer division of the row number by 10 would do:

```
df = pd.read_csv(data, header=None, names=["key", "value"])
df["index"] = [i // 10 for i in range(len(df))]
df = df.pivot("index", "key", "value")
```

<sup>FTR: if you have more than say a few billion records (> free GB of your RAM), then use http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-chunking</sup>

Comment: I do love your solution, it's nice and minimalistic.

Comment: #df = pd.read_csv(r'D:\\Files\\abc.txt', header=None, names=["key", "value"])
# df["index"] = [i // 10 for i in range(len(df))]
# df.pivot("index", "key", "value")
# df.to_csv(r'D:\\Files\\abc.csv', sep=',')

Comment: @Aprillion I am not getting any error message it not generating the needed file . It add one more column with ranking and nothing else. the file remains same. i have posted my code in previous comment . I dont know how to put code in comment

Comment: ,key,value,index
0,Open,2.9300000000000002,0
1,High,2.9700000000000002,0
2,Low,2.8300000000000001,0
3,Close,2.8999999999999999,0
4,Volume,631100,0
5,Adj Close,2.8999999999999999,0
6,SMA_20,3.2214999999999998,0
7,SMA_50,3.0767999999999969,0
8,date_of_trade,2016-02-05 00:00:00,0
9,code,1PG,0
10,Open,6.9900000000000002,1
11,High,7.0999999999999996,1
12,Low,6.9000000000000004,1
13,Close,6.9000000000000004,1
14,Volume,4300,1
15,Adj Close,6.9000000000000004,1
16,SMA_20,7.1709999999999994,1
17,SMA_50,7.3382000000000005,1
18,date_of_trade,2016-02-05 00:00:00,1
19,code,ONT,1

Comment: @Aprillion i put file generated in my previous comment

Comment: I was using ipython notebook, which prints the last statement. I updated my answer to change the `df` variable with the pivoted table. You didn't say anything about saving the result to a new file in your question though,, is that what you want?

Comment: yes i wanted to save it to file. my mistake i should assign dataframe back and save to file Thanks. working now @Aprillion

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you really need the Pandas machinery here. You could just do the transposition by hand:

```
from csv import DictWriter
from toolz import partition

cols = 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Adj Close', 'SMA_20', 'SMA_50', 'date_of_trade', 'code'

with open('old.csv') as old, open('new.csv', 'w') as new:
    writer = DictWriter(new, cols)
    writer.writeheader()

    for lines in partition(len(cols), old):
        writer.writerow(dict(l.strip().split(',') for l in lines))
```

Comment: OP doesn't want to convert 2 columns to 2 rows but to many rows - a new record begins every 10 rows in the input

Comment: yes u  r right first column contain column name second column contain values. the set of 10 is repeated.

Comment: yes i could do it by hand but this list get updated daily .and want to use it for report generation

Comment: Unless the number of columns changes, I see no problems with that.

Comment: Plus, this method doesn't load the entire data set in memory (only one row at a time), so this is fully scalable.

Comment: @Kris hope you are not suggesting pandas are not [scalable](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-chunking)

Comment: Just try your method on a data set that's bigger than your ram capacity.

Comment: It is not an issue with Pandas, it's the way you choose to use it that isn't scalable.

Comment: sure, for a few million records - wait, those would still fit just fine into today's memory. let's start again: for a few billion records, you would have to process the file by chunks in Pandas and use more fancy tricks to be able to run any reporting on top of the pivoted data (such as group by + average), but that would be a different Q&A in my opinion

Comment: Dude, don't get me wrong, your solution is nice. It just isn't scalable, which doesn't mean it's worthless. It's still great. The scalability thing was just a side note.